# Shopping List - Local storage issue (Ionic 2)

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

As part of my recipe app I am creating a shopping list, so the user can click a button on one page, take the ingredients and it displays on another page. Simple eh? Not for me.

The main issue that I have is after following tutorials I have managed to add local storage if the data is on the **same page**. Where I am transferring between pages I am having the following issues.

1. Only the 1st recipe will be added.
2. You have to close/refresh the app to changed the items.

If someone could help me out with the issues about that would be great.

I have a details page whereby you can add the ingredients

Details.html

```
<h1 (click)="submit(api.ingredientLines)">Add to shopping list</h1>
```

Details.ts

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dataService: Data, private navParams: NavParams, public storage: Storage) {
    console.log(navParams.get('id'));
    this.id = navParams.get('id');
}

submit(ingredientLines) {
    console.log(ingredientLines);
    this.storage.set('myData', ingredientLines); 
}
```

Shopping-list.html

```
    <ion-item>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of ingredientLines">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span>{{item}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ion-item>
```

shopping-list.ts

```
export class ShoppingListPage {

    public ingredientLines;
  public recipes;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public storage: Storage, public navParams: NavParams, public dataService: Data) {
    this.ingredientLines = navParams.get('ingredientLines');  
    this.getData();
}

getData() {
  this.storage.get('myData').then((data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.recipes = data;
  }));
}
```

console.log of when submit is pressed

[image]

I hope this gives you a good enough idea.

Comment: Can you include sample output of all the `console.log`? Would help i think unless you provide a fiddle.

Comment: Would you provide code how did you push ShoppingListPage  in nav?

Comment: and you used 'myData' for both `ingredientLines` and `recipies`, so data will be overwritten

Comment: @RezaRahmati This is just navigating manually though the tabs, I have changed it to just use `ingredientLines` and issue is still apparent

Comment: @BA1995 when you are reading from `navParams`, you should have put it before, otherwise how does it have data